# jquery html of class/id and itselfs html

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

I want to alert the html of class/id with its children AND itselfs element like this:

```
<div id="selectme">somechildren...</div>
```

I want the exact same alert as the HTML code above by selecting the "selectme" ID.. whats the function(s) for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element in question has siblings, you can `clone` the selected element, wrap a parent element around it (in this case I've used a `div`), select that new parent element, and get the `html` of that:

```
var html = $("#selectme").clone().wrap("<div>").parent().html();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/5E9b8/2/).

If the element doesn't have any siblings, you can just do:

```
var html = $("#selectme").parent().html();
```

Comment: thx thats it.. i will accept it. i tought maybe theres a function for it. but its a nice trick :)

Comment: something like `outerHtml` is not supported by JavaScript engines

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert($("#selectme").parent().clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
alert($('#selectme').parent().html())
```

although your question is pretty blurry...